# Get back changes which were removed due to undo operation in TFS?

Tags: team-foundation-server

Mistakenly, I did undo operation on my TFS checkout and I lost all my changes.

Is there a way to get back changes or reverse of undo operation?

I checked, I can not restore with Windows restore option.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588788/is-there-a-way-to-get-back-changes-which-removed-due-to-undo-operation-in-tfs